# How to get the logged in user's Id in a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Using Microsoft ASP.NET Identity, how can I get the Id of the user that's been authenticated in a controller?

Comment: Is the user not going to continue being authenticated?  If they are authenticated, the controller already knows about it in HttpContext.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  The controller should already have access to this information.

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? Forms or Identity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Dont forget

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

Answer (score 4):

The controller can already access this through its `HttpContext` object.

You can get the username of the currently logged in user using `User.Identity.Name`.

From there, you can query your users table to get their `Id` if that's what you need.